# Paste multiple column values with column name with empty values

Tags: r, data.table

```
dt <- data.table(v1 = c("", "17-Sep-2019"),
                   v2 = c("", "17-Sep-2019"))
  cols <- paste0("v",1:2)
  dt[, do.call(paste, Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ':'),
                                    lubridate::dmy(.SD), 
                                    toupper(gsub(".*(\\(.*\\)).*","\\1", names(.SD))))),
     .SDcols = cols]
```

I want the code to return c(NA, "2019-09-17:V1 2019-09-17:V2")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
dt <- data.table(v1 = c("", "17-Sep-2019"), v2 = c("", "17-Sep-2019"))
cols <- paste0("v",1:2)
dt[, fifelse(v1!="",  
    do.call(paste, Map(function(x, v) paste0(as.Date(x, "%d-%b-%Y"), ":", toupper(v)), .SD, cols)),
    NA_character_), .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: What if names of columns is dynamic, so how to edit the Map function I mentioned in the example.